# Render crops image from compositor

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image

I made a 3D tracking, and noticed that after rendering the image is cropped. I got the camera through the 3D tracking. Why is this happening and can we fix it without making new 3D tracking?

Here is a screenshot at the top is the compositor, and below is render:
[image]

Comment: check to make sure that your render settings for the scene are set to the same size as the background image.

Comment: @David Thank you! That was my mistake! :) It worked! 
P.S. I don't know, how to mark a comment as the answer?)

Comment: He needs to post an answer, if he doesn't do it in around 12hrs someone else can post it instead for you.

Comment: @David Post that as an answer for the OP please :D

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise answered.

Comment: @David Awesome, UV'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compositing a render over an image you have to make sure that your render dimensions for the scene are set to the same size as the background image.
[image: render dimensions]

---

Your other option (say if the picture quite large) is to scale the picture to match the render size.

That can be done by adding a *Scale* node set to *Render Size*, which will give you a node setup like this.
[image: compositor nodes]